# Azure VM Core size

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-vm

I have spun two VMs in azure, one with size *Standard D4s v3 (4 vcpus, 16GiB memory)* and the second with size *Standard D4as_v4 (4vcpus, 16GiB memory)*.

However if i run the cmdlet `Get-WmiObject –class Win32_processor | ft NumberOfCores,NumberOfLogicalProcessors` from powershell, the first VM says four as Number of Cores but for the second one it is only two.

Please can someone help me in understanding this anomaly?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I tried testing it on my subscription and it resulted in giving me both the vm’s no. of cores as 2 .

The reason for some VM series showing no of cores as 2 , even when you have created a VM with 4 vcpu’s is because they have `vcpu:core 2:1`. While others can have `vcpu:core ratio as 1:1` . When I checked for `D4_sv3` and `D4_asv4` both had 2:1 ratio.

[image]

[image]

**Reference:** [Overview of the Azure Compute Unit - Azure Virtual Machines | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/virtual-machines/acu)

Answer (score 1):

- Standard D4s v3 have processor: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2673 v3 @ 2.40GHz
- Standard D4as_v4 have processor: AMD EPYC 7452 32-Core Processor

take a look on picture below and pay attention to Benchmark: AMD is much faster.

[image]